# Get this element Attribute and use it on other element

Tags: jquery, this, attr

So... What I want is the following:

When I .click an element with an id starting with 'menu' it will get its attr value='value' into a variable and use it on the next function.

Here's the source:

**index.html**

```
<div id='menuBar' >
  <img id='menu01' src='/si/img/menu.apresentacao.jpg' value='apresentacao' >
  <img id='menu02' src='/si/img/menu.servicos.jpg' value='servicos' >
</div>
```

**jquery.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('img[id^='menu']').click( function(){

  var menuValue = $(this).attr('value');

  $('div#contentBox').fadeOut(300, function() {
   $('div#contentBox').replaceWith('<div id="contentBox">' + menuValue + '</div>');
  });
 });

});
```

**variables.js**

```
var servicos = "<p id='title'>Serviços</p><br><p id='text'>text text</p><br>";
```

Thanks in advance*

Comment: A little tip: don't use selectors like $("div#id"), it would cause jQuery to iterate through all divs on your page which is really, really bad for your performance. You should use only $("#id") because ids are unique by definition and this selector uses javascript's built-in getElementById() - the fastest way to select a DOM element.

Comment: There is a typo here: $('img[id^='menu']').click... Does this is exact string from your code? If so change single quote to double quote here $("img[id^='menu']")

Comment: $('img[id^='menu']'); fix this puting some ++: $('img[id^='+menu+']') if exist a variable called menu.

Comment: As for your problem - is that your actual code? If so, it contains a syntax error in your first selector. It should be: $('img[id^="menu"]') - note the double quotes inside the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem with your code is that your selector is malformed and therefor doesn't work:

```
$('img[id^='menu']').click( function(){
  ^        ^    ^ ^
  |        |    | |
  |        |    | \__ Closing single quote
  |        |    |
  |        |    \__ Opening single quote
  |        |
  |        |
  |        \__ Closing single quote
  |
  \__ Opening single quote


  ====> does not compute!
```

What it should be, is this (note the double quotes around "menu:):

```
$('img[id^="menu"]').click( function(){
           ^    ^
           |    |
           \    /
            \  /
             \/
              \_Double quotes, yay!
```

… and it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/HnsTu/

Comment: With the amount of brackets and quotes we're looking at each day, this  stuff happens. No need to worry, mate.

Comment: The problem is that now I want the value of the 'var = menuValue' to show up as a variable. (so it goes to my variable.js file grab the corresponding variable value instead of just showing up as plain text)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `var servicos` use an object with the value of your image as a key.

```
var menuValueContent = {'servicos': '<p>....</p>', 'apre': '...'};
```

and in your click handler you can use `menuValueContent[menuValue]` to get the new content.